# Android SDK updated Styles.xml Error

Tags: android, eclipse

I updated Android SDK to the last updates and When I create a android project on Eclipse with the Tools for Android updated, this not generate styles.xml and my AndroidManifest has errors with this. The src folder is empty don't generate the minimum template from activity, etc. I don't encountered information searching with google, I'm a student and My teacher has same problem on his laptop.

The error description, the folders generated on my project and the AndroidManifest file:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3HEj.jpg

All of the project is recent created. The project is created with minimum API 19, objective API 19 and compile with API 19. And I have all API downloaded.

I tried to make clean install on ubuntu and It has same problem.

Comment: please put your output to your question!

Comment: @Constantine Okey, Sorry. I put an image album with three images with my eclipse workspace.